# How to unsubscribe sqs queue from sns in boto

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an sqs queue which is subscribed to an sns topic using boto.sns.subscribe() method. What should I do to unsubscribe the queue from the topic ? I tried the boto sns method unsubscribe(subscription) as below but it gives me error.

```
BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
{"Error":{"Code":"InvalidParameter","Message":"Invalid parameter: SubscriptionId","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"41db2d5b-5ab8-561a-9846-63e4d0c1e795"}
```

Code I tried :

```
arn = str(self._sqs_connection_obj.get_queue_attributes(queue, attribute='QueueArn')['QueueArn'])
SNSHandler()._sns_connection_obj.unsubscribe(arn)
```

queue - is my sqs queue object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unsubscribe()` method for SNS takes the ARN of the Subscription (not the ARN of the SQS queue).

Use the SNS `get_all_subscriptions()` method to retrieve information about the SNS subscriptions, then extract the ARN of the subscriber to remove.

It will look something like:

```
'SubscriptionArn': 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:743112987576:my-topic:5644ff1b-56df-486d-8317-e8889616aa7c'
```

Here's the response from the `get_all_subscriptions()` call:

```
>>> import boto.sns
>>> import boto.sqs
>>> sns=boto.sns.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
>>> sns.get_all_subscriptions()
{u'ListSubscriptionsResponse': {u'ListSubscriptionsResult': {u'NextToken': u'AAFZ4NK21b0q15BrHPHV9fYxNWD16pSk2A7dvMEIWe1LWQ==', u'Subscriptions': [{u'Owner': u'743112987576', u'Endpoint': u'arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:743112987576:stack-queue', u'Protocol': u'sqs', u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:743112987576:my-topic', u'SubscriptionArn': u'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:743112987576:my-topic:5644ff1b-56df-486d-8317-e8889616aa7c'}]}, u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u'641f5f6a-ea0f-51e7-929b-11a8c304fd62'}}}
```

So, the best choice is to look through the list of subscriptions to find the one with the **Endpoint** equal to your queue ARN.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I extract the subscriber ARN from the `get_all_subscription()` if I have the queue object ?